# IndexedDB slow when repeating the same request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, indexeddb, angular2-observables

I'm implementing `IndexedDB` in `AngularJS 2` using `TypeScript` and `Observables`. I found that opening the `IndexedDB` database and then fetching 500 records took less than a second. However, with that database connection still open, fetching the same data again took around 110 seconds. I've tried various options including cursors to retrieve the data all with the same results. There are only around 4000 records in this store too.

I've included some example code below to try and illustrate what I'm trying to do. Executing `OfflineService.test()` as the entry point.

```
export class OfflineService {
    constructor(private indexedDbService: IndexedDbService) {
    }

    test(): void {
        this.indexedDbService.openDb()
            .subscribe((open: boolean) => {
                if (!open) {
                    // IndexedDB not supported
                    return;
                }
                this.indexedDbService.getObjectsById("items", 1, 500)
                    .subscribe((results: any[]) => {
                        // results returned in < 1 second

                        // retrieve again
                        this.indexedDbService.getObjectsById("items", 1, 500)
                            .subscribe((results: any[]) => {
                                // results returned in around 110 seconds
                            });
                    });
            });
    }
}

export class IndexedDbService {
    private db: any;

    openDb(): Observable<boolean> {
        return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            try {
                if (this.db) {
                    observer.next(true);
                    observer.complete();
                    return;
                }

                const request = indexedDB.open("testDb", 1);
                request.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
                    event.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore("items", { keyPath: "Id", autoIncrement: false });
                };
                request.onsuccess = () => {
                    this.db = request.result;
                    observer.next(true);
                    observer.complete();
                };
                request.onerror = () => {
                    observer.next(false);
                    observer.complete();
                };
            } catch (err) {
                observer.next(false);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    }

    getObjectsById(storeName: string, lowerId: number, upperId: number): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            try {
                const results: any[] = [];
                const store = this.getObjectStore(storeName, false);
                const request = store.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerId, upperId));
                request.onsuccess = () => {
                    var cursor = request.result;
                    if (cursor) {
                        results.push(cursor.value);
                        cursor.continue();
                    } else {
                        observer.next(results);
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                };
                request.onerror = (event) => {
                    observer.error(Error(event.target.errorCode));
                };
            } catch (err) {
                observer.error(err);
            }
        });
    }

    private getObjectStore(storeName: string, writable: boolean): any {
        const transaction = this.db.transaction(storeName, writable ? "readwrite" : "readonly");
        return transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not sound normal. But you're more likely to get help if your code is a minimal self-contained example of the problem. Like, try getting rid of the observables and see if that fixes it. If not, include the code to set up your database and actually run the example.

Comment: @dumbmatter I included all of the above code because I wasn't sure if it was Observables or IndexedDB causing the problem. Turns out it was neither. See my answer below. I agree with you though that minimal code or more code that can be run is always best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that it wasn't anything to do with `IndexedDB` or `Observables`. It was just that after loading the first set of results, the second call to the `IndexedDB` was slower simply because of more memory being used. Clearing the original results before making the second call fixed the performance problem.